How do I change my Input/Output labels back to the default?
My notebooks have a non-standard In/Out labels.
They look like this:

I changed label style so long ago, I can't remember how I did it.
I've tried changing the CellLabelTemplate option, but that didn't work.
How can I set it back to the original behavior?

See CellLabelStyle and Changing the style of In and Out and font of input and output cells.

@MarcoB Thank you. I saw that one, but didn't see a way of removing the date/time that was appearing in my In/Out labels

The option is called EvaluationCompletionAction. Use the following to get the default behaviour:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction -> {}]

or the following to turn on the timestamps again:
SetOptions[$FrontEnd, EvaluationCompletionAction -> {"AddTimeStamp"}]


Bingo! That was the one.  I don't know how I found that Option in the first place.
